# What should be the 'count' paramerter of MPI_reduce when using derived types created with MPI_Type_struct()?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm not sure I understand correctly the difference between the 'count' parameter in :

```
    int MPI_Reduce(void *sendbuf, void *recvbuf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, 
           MPI_Op op, int root, MPI_Comm comm);
```

and the 'blocklens' parameter of :

```
int MPI_Type_struct(int count,
               int blocklens[],
               MPI_Aint indices[],
               MPI_Datatype old_types[],
               MPI_Datatype *newtype);
```

Say I want to perform a reduction of my own type :

```
typedef struct buffers_s
{
   double *buf1, *buf2;
} Buffers;
```

where buf1 and buf2 are both allocated to N elements.

Then when calling MPI_Type_struct() to create a new mpi type 'Custom_MPI_Type' based on 'Buffers', I would set 'count' to 2, blocklens[0] to N and blocklens[1] to N too.

Then when the MPI type is created, assuming I have also created a reduction operator 'MyOp', I would call MPI_Reduce() with 'datatype' set to 'Custom_MPI_Type'. What then should be the value of the 'count' parameter ?

From my experience setting it to N works, however I don't really understand the meaning of that, considering I've already specified that the MPI type I've just created was made of 2 blocks of length N.

Said differently, when using MPI_Reduce() with arrays of basic types such as MPI_FLOAT, the 'count' parameter specifies the number of elements of type MPI_FLOAT starting at the address given as a first argument of MPI_Reduce()... so logically I would have expected, when using a custom Datatype, to set count to 1 element of type Custom_MPI_Type, provided that MPI already knows this type consists of 2 blocks of N elements of a given basic MPI_Datatype such as MPI_DOUBLE.

Could someone explain all that ?

Comment: Here is a code that does the thing : http://pastebin.com/SDzrG4VD
What I don't get is why I have to put 'size' line 217 although I already specified that lines 25 and 26.

Answer (score 1):

Derived datatypes in MPI do not generally work with types such as your `Buffers`. Jonathan Dursi has explained why in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13435977/1374437). The structure datatype is mean to work with C/C++ structures such as:

```
#define N 1000

typedef struct buffers_s
{
   double buf1[N], buf2[N];
} Buffers;
```

In this case the offsets of `buf1` and `buf2` from the beginning of an instance of `Buffers` are always the same unlike in the case when `buf1` and `buf2` both point to dynamically allocated memory.

This said, the `blocklengths` parameter of `MPI_Type_create_struct` (`MPI_Type_struct` is deprecated in MPI-2 and even removed in MPI-3.0 so you should not use it) is used to describe the shape of the datatype itself. `blocklengts[i]` tells MPI how many elements of type `old_types[i]` are contained in the `i`-th element of the new datatype. For the above structure, `blocklengths[0] = blocklengths[1] = N`.

The `count` argument to `MPI_Reduce` tells MPI how many elements of `datatype` are there to be reduced. If `datatype` is your structure datatype it means how many instances of the structure are there. Continuing on the example code above, if you have an array of 10 instances of `Buffers`, e.g.:

```
Buffers bufs[10];
```

then you'd supply `10` in the `count` argument. This is completely orthogonal to the block count in the structure type constructor. The total number of elements communicated by a single process would be `count` times the sum of all elements of `blocklengts[]`. Your have correctly concluded that if only one element of the derived datatype is being reduced, then `count` should be set to 1.