# MPI_reduce() with custom Datatype containing dynamically allocated arays : segmentation fault

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I don't get why MPI_Reduce() does a segmentation fault as soon as I use a custom MPI datatype which contains dynamically allocated arrays. Does anyone know ? The following code crashes with 2 processors, inside the MPI_Reduce().
However If I remove the member double *d int MyType and changes the operator and MPI type routines accordingly, the reduction is done without any problem.

Is there a problem using dynamically allocated arrays or is there something fundamentally wrong with what I do :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>



typedef struct mytype_s
{
    int c[2];
    double a;
    double b;
    double *d;
} MyType;



void CreateMyTypeMPI(MyType *mt, MPI_Datatype *MyTypeMPI)
{
    int block_lengths[4];                        // # of elt. in each block
    MPI_Aint displacements[4];                   // displac.
    MPI_Datatype typelist[4];                    // list of types
    MPI_Aint start_address, address;            // use for calculating displac.
    MPI_Datatype myType;

    block_lengths[0] = 2;
    block_lengths[1] = 1;
    block_lengths[2] = 1;
    block_lengths[3] = 10;

    typelist[0] = MPI_INT;
    typelist[1] = MPI_DOUBLE;
    typelist[2] = MPI_DOUBLE;
    typelist[3] = MPI_DOUBLE;

    displacements[0] = 0;

    MPI_Address(&mt->c, &start_address);
    MPI_Address(&mt->a, &address);
    displacements[1] = address - start_address;

    MPI_Address(&mt->b,&address);
    displacements[2] = address-start_address;

    MPI_Address(&mt->d, &address);
    displacements[3] = address-start_address;

    MPI_Type_struct(4,block_lengths, displacements,typelist,MyTypeMPI);
    MPI_Type_commit(MyTypeMPI);
}




void MyTypeOp(MyType *in, MyType *out, int *len, MPI_Datatype *typeptr)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i=0; i < *len; i++)
    {
        out[i].a += in[i].a;
        out[i].b += in[i].b;
        out[i].c[0] += in[i].c[0];
        out[i].c[1] += in[i].c[1];

        for (j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            out[i].d[j] += in[i].d[j];
        }
    }
}




int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyType mt;
    MyType mt2;
    MPI_Datatype MyTypeMPI;
    MPI_Op MyOp;
    int rank;
    int i;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);


    mt.a = 2;
    mt.b = 4;
    mt.c[0] = 6;
    mt.c[1] = 8;
    mt.d = calloc(10,sizeof *mt.d);
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) mt.d[i] = 2.1;

    mt2.a = 0;
    mt2.b = 0;
    mt2.c[0] = mt2.c[1] = 0;
    mt2.d = calloc(10,sizeof *mt2.d);


    CreateMyTypeMPI(&mt, &MyTypeMPI);
    MPI_Op_create((MPI_User_function *) MyTypeOp,1,&MyOp);

    if(rank==0) printf("type and operator are created now\n");

    MPI_Reduce(&mt,&mt2,1,MyTypeMPI,MyOp,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(rank==0)
    {




        for (i=0; i<10; i++) printf("%f ",mt2.d[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(mt.d);
    free(mt2.d);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh I think I get it : the memory block allocated dynamically is not contiguous with the previous members of my structure, however MPI uses the displacement array that I give him and tries to access the 10 MPI_DOUBLE after the member 'b', which results in a segmentation fault.

How is it possible then to reduce such structure with a dynamic array ?

Comment: You should make MyType.d an array.Or if you want dynamic memory, make a packet of memory containing all the data inside the struct and pointed, using memcpy.

Comment: Yes I need the array to be dynamic, the code above is jsut a small example, in my real code there are many big arrays who therefore need to be dynamically allocated. 
Could you be more specific about your proposition with memcpy ?

Comment: Do not use `memcpy`. MPI provides the `MPI_Pack` and `MPI_Unpack` calls to perform portable data (un-)packing into user supplied memory buffers. The idea bascally is to construct the message on your own instead of creating a data type as MPI is simply not able to follow pointer refrences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at your struct:

```
typedef struct mytype_s
{
    int c[2];
    double a;
    double b;
    double *d;
} MyType;

...

MyType mt;
mt.d = calloc(10,sizeof *mt.d);
```

And your description of this struct as an MPI type:

```
displacements[0] = 0;

MPI_Address(&mt->c, &start_address);
MPI_Address(&mt->a, &address);
displacements[1] = address - start_address;

MPI_Address(&mt->b,&address);
displacements[2] = address-start_address;

MPI_Address(&mt->d, &address);
displacements[3] = address-start_address;

MPI_Type_struct(4,block_lengths, displacements,typelist,MyTypeMPI);
```

The problem is, this MPI struct is only *ever* going to apply to the one instance of the structure you've used in the definition here.   You have no control at all of where `calloc()` decides to grab memory from; it could be anywhere in virtual memory.  The next one of these type you create and instantiate, the displacement for your `d` array will be completely different; and even using the same struct, if you change the size of the array with `realloc()` of the current `mt`, it could end up having a different displacement.

So when you send, receive, reduce, or anything else with one of these types, the MPI library will dutifully go to a probably meaningless displacement, and try to read or write from there, and that'll likely cause a segfault.

Note that this isn't an MPI thing; in using any low-level communications library, or for that matter trying to write out/read in from disk, you'd have the same problem.

Your options include manually "marshalling" the array into a message, either with the other fields or without; or adding some predictability to where d is located such as by defining it to be an array of some defined maximum size.

Comment: The combination of `MPI_Pack()` and `MPI_Unpack()` provides means to perform portable data marshalling. The data has to be packed before the call to `MPI_Reduce()` and the custom operation handler has to unpack each data element.