# Optimal way to create datatype for a structure with dynamic arrays MPI_Type_get_extent and MPI_Type_create_Struct

Tags: types, struct, parallel-processing, mpi

A structure need to be used when propagating messages wia MPI functions, e.g. MPI_Send, MPI_Recv.

```
     struct results
        {
        char filename[300];//text for file name the results to be stored in
        double *t;//time buffer 
        double *x;//X coordinate buffer
        double *y;//Y coordinate buffer
        double *z;//Z coordinate buffer
        } resultbuffer;
```

The size of fields are dynamically changing depending on "length"

```
     resultbuffer.t = (double*)calloc(length,sizeof(double));
     resultabuffer.x = (double*)calloc(length,sizeof(double));
     resultabuffer.y = (double*)calloc(length,sizeof(double));
     resultabuffer.z = (double*)calloc(length,sizeof(double));
```

---

Would it be optimal and work if I use

```
     MPI_Datatype struct_type,oldtypes[2]={MPI_CHAR,MPI_DOUBLE};
```

And multiply the length to 4 as of in any case all fields are same type double

```
     int blockcounts[2]={300,4*length};
     MPI_Aint offsets[2],extent;
     //setup description for the fields in the message structure 
     int ofst=0;
     for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            offsets[i]=ofst;
            MPI_Type_extent(oldtypes[i], &extent);
            ofst = ofst + blockcounts[i]*extent;
        } 

     // Now define structured type and commit it.
     MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blockcounts, offsets, oldtypes, &struct_type);
     MPI_Type_commit(&struct_type);
```

---

Or one need to define the fields and offsets for each field separately even if the types are same?

```
  MPI_Datatype struct_type,oldtypes[5]={MPI_CHAR,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_DOUBLE};
  int blockcounts[5]={300,length,length,length,length};
  MPI_Aint offsets[5],extent;
  //setup description for the fields in the message structure 
  int ofst=0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        offsets[i]=ofst;
        MPI_Type_extent(oldtypes[i], &extent);
        ofst = ofst + blockcounts[i]*extent;
    } 

    // Now define structured type and commit it.
    MPI_Type_create_struct(5, blockcounts, offsets, oldtypes, &struct_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&struct_type);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPI\_reduce() with custom Datatype containing dynamically allocated arays : segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434879/mpi-reduce-with-custom-datatype-containing-dynamically-allocated-arays-segme)

Comment: See some of the other questions in the "related" sidebar.  An MPI datatype describes both the _amount_ and the _layout_ of data, and it's just not the case that your calloc()ed arrays start at an offset of zero from the filename and are placed one after each other - each one could be anywhere in memory.  You'll have to find the offsets of each of the alloc'ed buffers and put those in the type_structure definition.  There are several Q&As listed that describe how to do this.

Comment: How about MPI_Type_indexed, would it help?